# ObjectC-Why can't I get the properties correctly using the class_copyPropertyList function?

Tags: objective-c, reflection, runtime

- macOS 11.5.2
- Xcode 13.2.1

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Class clazz = NSClassFromString(@"NSString");
        uint32_t count = 0;
        objc_property_t* properties = class_copyPropertyList(clazz, &count);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < count; i++){
            const char* name = property_getName(properties[i]);
            std::cout << name << std::endl;
        }
        free(properties);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I will take some snippets of the output：

```
hash
superclass
description
debugDescription
hash
superclass
description
debugDescription
vertexID
sha224
NS_isSourceOver
hash
superclass
description
debugDescription
...
```

From the output, we can find that properties such as hash, description, superclass, etc. will appear repeatedly several times, while some properties (such as UTF8String) do not appear in the result list.
How should I get the list of properties correctly?
I would appreciate it.

Comment: May be because `UTF8String` was declared as method without arguments.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Thanks for your help.Maybe you're right, but I do see UTF8String defined as an attribute in the NSString.h header file.
```objc
@property (nullable, readonly) const char *UTF8String NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER;
```

Comment: I think the reason is that NSString is a class cluster and the string objects aren’t actual instances of the NSString or NSMutableString classes but of one of their private subclasses.

Comment: @ChristosKoninis But instead of using an instance of a string to get the properties, I used the NSString class directly ,as can be seen from

 Class clazz = NSClassFromString(@"NSString");

Comment: @wzhengsen Yes you are using a class that has declared in its interface it implements a method, but that method is implemented by a private class not by the NSString directly, this is the class cluster pattern. So when you are asking in the runtime to get the methods of the NSString it returns nothing because an other private class implements them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing `UTF8String` come up as a property is that it's not declared as a property in the *main* declaration of `NSString`, but rather in a *category*. On macOS 12.2.1/Xcode 13.2.1, the declaration of `NSString` boils down to this:

```objectivec
@interface NSString : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding>
@property (readonly) NSUInteger length;
- (unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (instancetype)init NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

All other properties and methods on `NSString` are declared in categories immediately afterwards:

```objectivec
@interface NSString (NSStringExtensionMethods)

#pragma mark *** Substrings ***

/* To avoid breaking up character sequences such as Emoji, you can do:
    [str substringFromIndex:[str rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:index].location]
    [str substringToIndex:NSMaxRange([str rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:index])]
    [str substringWithRange:[str rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:range]
*/
- (NSString *)substringFromIndex:(NSUInteger)from;
- (NSString *)substringToIndex:(NSUInteger)to;

// ...

@property (nullable, readonly) const char *UTF8String NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER; // Convenience to return null-terminated UTF8 representation

// ...

@end
```

When a property is declared in a category on a type like this, it doesn't get emitted as an actual Obj-C property because categories [can only add *methods* to classes, and not instance variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html). When a category declares a property on a type, it must be backed by a *method* and not a traditional property.

You can see this with a custom class, too — on my machine,

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface MyClass: NSObject
@property (nullable, readonly) const char *direct_UTF8String NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER;
@end

@interface MyClass (Extensions)
@property (nullable, readonly) const char *category_UTF8String NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER;
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (const char *)direct_UTF8String {
    return "Hello, world!";
}

- (const char *)category_UTF8String {
    return "Hi there!";
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Class clazz = NSClassFromString(@"MyClass");
        
        printf("%s properties:\n", class_getName(clazz));
        uint32_t count = 0;
        objc_property_t* properties = class_copyPropertyList(clazz, &count);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < count; i++){
            printf("%s\n", property_getName(properties[i]));
        }
        
        free(properties);
        
        puts("-----------------------------------------------");
        
        printf("%s methods:\n", class_getName(clazz));
        Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(clazz, &count);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            SEL name = method_getName(methods[i]);
            printf("%s\n", sel_getName(name));
        }
        
        free(methods);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
MyClass properties:
direct_UTF8String
-----------------------------------------------
MyClass methods:
direct_UTF8String
category_UTF8String
```

If you remove the actual implementations of the `*UTF8String` methods from the class, the property remains declared, but the category method disappears (because it doesn't actually have a synthesized implementation because of how categories work):

```
MyClass properties:
direct_UTF8String
-----------------------------------------------
MyClass methods:
direct_UTF8String
```

---

As for how to adjust to this: it depends on what purpose you're trying to fetch properties for, and why you might need `UTF8String` specifically.

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` **declares** in its interface it implements methods, but it does not actually **implement** them, that is why when you print at runtime a list of the its  methods it does not print what you expect.
The methods are implemented by other private classes, and when you initialize a new instance of `NSString`, instead of getting an instance of `NSString` you get an instance of that private class that have the actual implementation.

You can see that by printing the class type of a string, the following prints `NSCFString` or `NSTaggedPointerString`, not `NSString`:

```
NSString* aString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"something"];
NSLog(@"%@", [aString class]);
```

And this prints `__NSCFConstantString`:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [@"a constant string" class]);
```

This pattern is called a class cluster pattern.
If you modify to dump the methods of the `NSCFString` you will get a "redactedDescription", it seems you are [prevented to query these classes](https://github.com/w0lfschild/macOS_headers/blob/master/macOS/Frameworks/CoreFoundation/1560.12/__NSCFConstantString.h).

Comment: This is true, but this does not explain what OP is seeing in terms of the property declarations. For instance, if you look at the _methods_ that `NSString` implements with `class_copyMethodList`, you'll see `UTF8String` is present — but it is not among the list of properties from `class_copyPropertyList`.

Comment: (Also, FWIW, `NSString` does implement `UTF8String` itself, without relying on a concrete class cluster member. You can see the `IMP` at runtime using `class_getMethodImplementation` passing in `NSString` itself (rather than `__NSCFString`), and if you pop open Foundation in a disassembler like [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com/) you can see the implementation in terms of an internal `_bytesInEncoding` function.)